# C# Object audit change tracker using Reflection and Recursion storing results in Mongo DB

Tags: c#, mongodb, recursion, reflection, audit

**Question:** Is there any existing software that does this?  The idea is to call a function, passing in 2 objects and use Reflection and Recursion to map out the list of any changed properties using Mongo DB "dot notation".  Pass in any 2 objects that inherit from a common type, and get a list or Json string to serialize in Mongo DB.

**Given:**

- All objects will be of simple types (int, string, bool, byte, etc.) *or*
- A class may inherit from a type called `BaseType`
- Any other object types are to be ignored.
- There may be array's or lists
- The array's or lists may contain other objects or arrays

**Example:**
A C# object is `foo.bar[2].baz.qux = 4;`  You may assume that `foo`, `bar`, `baz` are of type `BaseType` or `BaseType[]` and `qux` is a number.

Another example, array of arrays:`foo[3].bar[2].baz[5].qux = 4;` all of type `BaseType[]` except for `qux`.

Mongo Databases store "paths" to objects as a "dot notation".  The previous examples, in Mongo notation are:
`foo.bar[2].baz.qux` = `foo.bar.2.baz.qux`
`foo[3].bar[2].baz[5].qux` = `foo.3.bar.2.baz.5.qux`

What I want is a list of audit changes on all the properties.  We want to compare two objects of type `BaseType`.  The function call looks like this:

```
        public List<AuditField> AuditChanges(
           BaseType Old,
           BaseType New)
```

`AuditField` looks something like this:

```
class AuditField {
  string path;
  string oldValue;
  string newValue;
}
```

Simple example:
`var a = { foo= { bar= 6 }, baz = 2, qux = null};`
`var b = { foo= { bar= 4 }, baz = 2, qux = "banana"};`
`typeof(a) == typeof(b)`

result as JSON:
`AuditChanges(a, b) = [
  { path: "foo.bar", oldValue = 6, newValue = 4},
  { path: "qux", oldValue = null, newValue = "banana"},
]`

`baz` did not change so it's not in the list.

**NOTE:**
There are some catches:
1) List elements may be added or deleted.
2) Lists may be null or of zero count.
3) List elements may be re-arranged.  This should probably be handled as elements being removed and added.
4) Items of BaseType may be nulled (deleted)
5) Lists containing lists are tricky

Comment: Can you elaborate the problem you are facing here? I just see a task thats probably your job...

Comment: My question is that this seems like a task that could of been handled by another tool somewhere else and if anyone knows of that tool, then let me know.  I'm not asking you to do my job for me, although that would be nice. :)